# How to set a default value for a form partial variable in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-form

I am implementing a simple `controller` for a mini-project of mine. For the simplicity of this question, only two views matter: the `create` song, and `edit` song views. Both of these views contain the same form **fields**, so I created a form `partial` called `_form`.

Since the forms have *different* **purposes** - despite having the *same* **fields** - I pass on to the partial a couple of variables to specify the value of the submit button label, and the cancel button route.

For example:

**edit.blade.php:**

```
(...)

{!! Form::model($song, ['route' => ['songs.update', $song->slug], 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}

    @include('songs._form', [
        'submitButtonLabel' => 'Update',
        'returnRoute' => 'song_path',
        'params' => [$song->slug]
    ])

{!! Form::close() !!}

(...)
```

**create.blade.php:**

```
(...)

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'songs.store']) !!}

    @include('songs._form', [
        'submitButtonLabel' => 'Save',
        'returnRoute' => 'songs_path'
    ])

{!! Form::close() !!}

(...)
```

And here is the **_form.blade.php** partial:

```
(...)

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($submitButtonLabel, ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}

    {!! link_to_route($returnRoute, 'Cancel', isset($params) ? $params : [], ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'role' => 'button']) !!}
</div>
```

Now, **my question is** (finally):

As you can see, in the *Cancel* button of my **form partial**, I am using `isset($params) ? $params : []` to default the `$params` variable to `[]` when it is not set.

Is there a better way to do this? [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures), under *Echoing Data After Checking For Existence*, Laravel supports this alternative echo: `{{ $name or 'Default' }}`, but this does not work since I am trying to use it inside a `{!! !!}` block already...

So, is the `ternary operator` using the `isset()` function the best solution for this case? (The one I am currently using)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the variable `$params` an empty array (`[]`) in create.blade.php and remove the condition on your partial.

Then you can set the default value on your .blade files

As an alternative you can set a default value on your controller and send it as $params if they are not set (your slug).

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, but *that* is something I want to avoid. It makes sense not to worry about passing variables to the form partial that do not exist (in this case, the `[]`). For me, it makes sense that the `_form` partial should be the one accounted responsible for making such assertions; to acknowledge that it needs a variable which did not receive, and therefore defaulting it to the `[]`. I'm sorry I did not clarify this detail in the question.. I should have done it.